# laravel 8 manually deleted tables cant be generated from migration

Tags: php, laravel, database, database-migration

I manually deleted my all tables now i want ot re-migrate my tables. but it shows this error

**Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'mymedia.categories'
doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `categories` where `categories`.`deleted_at`
is null order by `id` asc)**

I tried these functions
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate --force
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan migrate:refresh

but problem does not solve!
please help me

Comment: Please add a screenshot for your migrations directory

Comment: Hi , You can use this command php artisan migrate:fresh. Run it if you are in localhost , donot use this command on live server , when tables have some data.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command when you are in localhost and don't need data

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

If you have seeder then run

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

Don't use these commands in live server when you have some data in live database

Comment: I run these function but shows this error https://prnt.sc/1u76bwb

Comment: Screenshot is not available , can you send it again

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2LaDfTA749hiP6_Z6CWHNNoAAL1gGux/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This says that you are fetching records not migrating.

Comment: Can you show me the command which you run?

Comment: php artisan migrate:fresh --seed

Answer (score 0):

But for now try this

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

Comment: it is not working. shows this error https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h2LaDfTA749hiP6_Z6CWHNNoAAL1gGux/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please add a screenshot for your migrations directory, and get me a screen shot for table anosundhan.categories

Comment: my skype name is: mohiuddin3824

Comment: Thanks Mostafa Hana. You solved my problem by skype.

Comment: You welcome, sir